# Python __init__ return failure to create

Tags: python, return, init

First off, I know that the `__init__()` function of a class in Python cannot return a value, so sadly this option is unavailable.

Due to the structure of my code, it makes sense to have data assertions (and prompts for the user to give information) inside the `__init__` function of the class. However, this means that the creation of the object can fail, and I would like to be able to gracefully recover from this.

I was wondering what the best way to continue with this is. I've considered setting a global boolean as a 'valid construction' flag, but I'd prefer not to.

Any other ideas (besides restructuring so assertions can happen outside of the initialization and values are passed in as arguments)? I'm basically looking for a way to have return 0 on success and return -1 on failure during initialization. (Like most C system calls)

Comment: Raise an exception.

Comment: Returning 0 on success and -1 on failure is very un-Pythonic. Error returns are bad, because they're easy to ignore, and verbose to handle. On top of that, using 0 and -1 as boolean values just adds confusion with no benefit. Don't true to use Python to write C code.

Comment: As @jsbueno points out in his answer, class instances are _initialized_ in `__init__()`, not created, which is why it doesn't `return` a value. Instead of using a global variable to detect failures doing this or throwing an exception, you could add a data member to your class to indicate its state and then check its value directly or call a method that returns its value after `__init__()` has been called to determine if anything (and possibly what) when wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could raise an exception when either assertio fail, or -, if you really don't want or can't work with exceptions, you can write the  `__new__` method in your classes - 
in Python, `__init__` is technically an "initializer" method - and it should fill in he attributes and acquire some of the resources and others your object will need during its life cycle - However, Python does define a real constructor, the `__new__` method, which is called prior to `__init__`- and unlike this, `__new__` actually does return a value: the newly created (uninitialized) instance itself.

So you can place your checks inside `__new__` and and simply return None is something fails - otherwise, return the result of the call to the superclass `__new__` method (one can't do the actual memory allocation for the object in pure Python, so ultimately you have to call a constructor written in native code in a superclass - usually this is `object.__new__` in the base of your class hierarchy.

**NB**: In Python 2, you must have `object` as the base class for your hierarchy - otherwise not only `__new__` is not called, as a whole lot of features added later to Python objects will just not work.  In short, `class MyClass(object):` , never `class MyClass:` - unless you are on Python3.

Comment: You say `__new__` is called before `__init__`. I just tried this, but `__new__` is NOT called when I create an instance of a class (Py2.7).

Comment: I found it. You need to extend object in your class. Without that, new will not be called!

Comment: No. If I omit the object base class,`__new__`  is not called automatically. Go figure!

Comment: No and again no. My print is not called, unless I add the object base class.

Comment: Hehe. Not only me falling in traps ;-) Would you add a note to your answer, so we can delete this discussion?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered raising an exception?  That is the usual way to signal a failure.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a @classmethod function? You can then check all the conditions and either create and initialize a new class, or return None. The calling function then just has to check if the returned class is not None.

Answer (score 0):

I returned `__init__` using some tricks.

This is how to set the error to 'try' by making an error in `__init__`.

Below is an example code.

```
import sys

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, test=None):
        if test is None:
            sys.exit(1)

        self.test = test
        print("do something __init__ here")

try:
    obj = MyClass()
except:
    obj = None

print(obj)
```